# Call static method from trait on generic type

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a trait with one function that does not take `self` as an argument:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn function(x: i32) -> i32;
}

struct Dummy;

impl MyTrait for Dummy {
    fn function(x: i32) -> i32 {
        x * 2
    }
}

fn call_method<T: MyTrait>(object: T) {
    let x = object.function(2);
}

fn main() {}
```

The user of the library is required to implement the trait for any type, usually an empty struct. One of my functions accepts a generic type that implements `MyTrait`. When I try to call the `function` method on the generic type, it gives me this error:

> error: no method named `function` found for type `T` in the current scope

I tried the solution in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342436/rust-invoke-trait-method-on-generic-type-parameter), but I get the same error. How can I call a static method on a generic type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> When I try to call the `function` method on the generic type, ...

Two things: first of all, depending on how you want to look at it, `function` *isn't* a method.  It's just a function that happens to live in the trait's namespace (*a.k.a.* an "associated function").

Secondly, you're *not* trying to call `function` on the type, you're calling it on a value of that type.  This is impossible because, again, it's not a method; it doesn't have a `self` parameter.

The solution is to *actually* call the `function` associated function on the generic type, which looks like this:

```rust
fn call_method<T: MyTrait>(object: T) {
    let x = T::function(2);
}
```

Sometimes, this won't be specific enough.  If you need to be more specific, you can *also* write the above as:

```
fn call_method<T: MyTrait>(object: T) {
    let x = <T as MyTrait>::function(2);
}
```

The two are semantically *identical*; it's just that the second is more specific and more likely to resolve when you have lots of traits involved.

Answer (score 3):

Following on DK. answer, you don't actually need to pass "object: T" as an argument to your function.

You can just do

```
fn call_method<T: MyTrait>() {
    let x = T::function(2);
}
```

In fact, if I got it right, you are not passing this struct to the function but merely linking it through the T, so there is no move/borrow semantics involved. *But I might be wrong here*.

Comment: From `main` function, `call_method` function can then be called as `call_method::<Dummy>()`.